# Replacing mirrored dynamic boot disk hard drive with a larger one (Windows Server operating system)

Tags: hard-drive

I am looking for a non-destructive solution to replace the boot (OS) hard drive in one of my servers. The hard drive holds both the operating system (Windows Server) and EFI partition. The OS partition is mirrored to another disk. Both mirrored disks are dynamic.

Screenshot from disk manager here

[image]

I have looked for many varieties of solution proposals, but none of them so far (except installing a fresh windows, deleting the OS partition and replacing the OS partition with the OS partition from the original drive) seems to be data proof or reliable.

The conditions for a proposed solutions should cover that:

1. The new disk (after cloning/copying/preparing) is bootable to OS
2. No data is lost.
3. The solution is built in to Windows OS or provided by third party software.
4. The solution is safe (in case of need to return to original scenario).

Any suggestions and opinions are welcome. :)

Comment: So you are running Windows software RAID on a SERVER?  I hope that is a experimental setup and NOT a production system. AND you just discovered why professional sys-admins want a hardware raid controller and a full-disk mirror for the OS drive.

Comment: It was prepared before my time unfortunately. I always use hardware RAID in my systems. That's why I touch this one with caution, not to mess up and cause server down time.

Comment: I get it. I have inherited some predecessors mistakes myself too.... I would never trust a clone made from inside a running OS. Running the cloning tool from other boot-media is in my opinion much safer and usually also quicker. But you need some downtime for the duration of making the clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would have been so much easier if you had a real hardware raid with a proper disk-mirror:
Replace disk 2 with a bigger disk. Let the RAID restore its mirroring.
Then do the same for disk 1.
Afterwards expand C:.

But this is software RAID:
Forget about point 4. This is going to be scary. BACKUP FIRST!!!!
Break the mirror. Take the 2nd disk out of the equation altogether.
Then switch the #1 disk back from dynamic to basic disk.
After that is done you can make a regular full-disk clone to the new disk with your disk-cloning utility of choice.
Then boot from the new, bigger disk and expand the C: partition into the free space at the end.
And if you want you can then go back to the same style of software raid as you originally had.

Comment: I also thought to go through with the above steps. The only part that still is a bit shaky in my head is the conversion part from dynamic to basic. Besides the usual tools that Server OS provides, I found also a licensed Easeus partition manager on that server. I think that would be the only way to convert without data loss.

Comment: Dynamic to basic can simply be done with the Windows Disk Administrator and will normally  NOT incur data-loss.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following steps to solve the problem:

- Broke the mirror and removed the unused disk.
- Converted the OS disk from dynamic to basic using Easeus. The option was not available under Windows Server OS.
- Cloned the OS disk to the new hard drive with larger capacity.
- Shut down the server, removed the old OS hDD, let the server boot from the new HDD with the clone.

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).